# prim's algorithm generated maze missing walls

Tags: c#, wpf, algorithm, maze

So I'm implementing a maze generator using prim's algorithm.
the maze itself generates pretty much fine, however two (touching) walls would always be missing.

the mazes I'm generating (the right and bottom walls are missing):

### [Maze 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jp1co.png)

here the left and top walls are missing:

### [Maze 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRHrY.png)

The code I use to generate the maze:

```
int _height = 50;
int _width = 50;
private bool[,] maze = new bool[_height, _width];


private void generateMaze()
{
    //_height = 50
    //_width = 50
    List<MazeCell> walls = new List<MazeCell>();
    int randX = genRand(1, _height-1);
    int randY = genRand(1, _width-1);
    maze[randX, randY] = true;
    MazeCell start = new MazeCell(randX, randY, null);

    for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
        {
            if ((i == 0 && j == 0) || (i != 0 && j != 0))
                continue;
            try
            {
                if (maze[randX + i, randY + j])
                    continue;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                continue;
            }
            walls.Add(new MazeCell(randX + i, randY + j, start));
        }
    }

    while (walls.Count > 0)
    {
        int index = genRand(0, walls.Count - 1);
        MazeCell cur = walls[index];
        MazeCell op = cur.opposite();
        walls.RemoveAt(index);
        try
        {
            if(!maze[cur.x, cur.y])
            {
                if(!maze[op.x, op.y])
                {
                    maze[cur.x, cur.y] = true;
                    maze[op.x, op.y] = true;

                    for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
                        {
                            if (i == 0 && j == 0 || i != 0 && j != 0)
                                continue;
                            try
                            {
                                if (maze[op.x + i, op.y + j])
                                    continue;
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                continue;
                            }
                            walls.Add(new MazeCell(op.x + i, op.y + j, op));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
    }
}

private int genRand(int min, int max)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    return rnd.Next(min, max);
}
```

And the mazeCell class:

```
public class MazeCell
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public bool passage = false;
    MazeCell parent;

    public MazeCell(int x, int y, MazeCell parent)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public MazeCell opposite()
    {
        if (x.CompareTo(parent.x) != 0)
            return new MazeCell(x + x.CompareTo(parent.x), y, this);
        if (y.CompareTo(parent.y) != 0)
            return new MazeCell(x, y + y.CompareTo(parent.y), this);
        return null;
    }
}
```

the code is an adaptation of java code I found here: http://jonathanzong.com/blog/2012/11/06/maze-generation-with-prims-algorithm

I can't find where it suddenly decides to remove walls.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you have height and width of 50 does that include the right and bottom walls?  If you index starts at zero then genRand(1, _height-1) and genRand(1, _width-1); are random.  So you would need the height and width to be 50 + 1 and then put a solid wall at index 50 (both row and column).  Or changes height-1 to height -2 as well as width- 1 to width - 2.  then add solid wall to index 50 (row and column).

Comment: @jdweng the 50 does include the walls, however the disappearing walls can also be the left and top walls, it seems completely random which of the two happens. I've updated the question with an example of both.

Comment: BTW you shouldn't keep creating new instances of the `Random` class. Do it once and then use that instance over and over. That way you can also create it with a seed value when you want to test in a repeatable manner.

Comment: Instead of using an Exception to detect the case where op.x+i and op.y+j is outside the maze you should use an explicit comparison with the minimum and maximum bounds you want to use. This may be where your algorithm is leaking off into the border you want to maintain. It's also a really bad practice to catch all Exceptions like this, if it's an index exception you are looking for, use that instead.

Comment: @IanMercer after making the random a global variable and replacing all the try catch statements with comparisons, it still messes up the border.

Comment: @AlexanderdeHaan the first one was a BTW not an answer; the second one was more of a "do this so you can check your logic is correct". Catching all Exceptions could be hiding some other problem in your code. Maybe edit your question to remove all the try catches so we can see what your logic looks like and so you can be sure it's not crashing out on some other bad array reference.

Comment: The outside wall should not be random.  You should have on opening in the outside side wall  for the start and one opening in the outside wall for the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and if you move the `new Random` outside the method to a member variable (so it's created just once), then it seems to work just fine.

There is no code to ensure that there is a boundary around the edge of the whole maze: the maze will happily wander right up to any edge. What you are seeing is an artifact of non-randomness caused by resetting Random every time.

If set Random to the same seed over and over in that method I see long runs down two sides also.

Here's sample output for 15x15 with proper random values:

```
XXXXXXXXX X X X
X         X X X
X X XXXXXXXXXXX
X X X     X   X
XXXXXXXXX X X X
X X         X X
X XXX XXXXXXX X
  X   X   X   X
XXXXX X X XXX X
X     X X      
XXXXXXX X XXXXX
X X   X X X   X
X XXX XXXXXXX X
  X X X X      
XXX X X XXXXXXX
```

Comment: I've moved the new Random outside the method now, however after some tests concerning maze sizes it seems to be the case that it'll generate random walls on maze sizes that are either an even number, or bigger than 33

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to tackle this more from a graph-based perspective and not from some specific representation of a "maze".

See also my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57398253/why-does-my-implementation-of-randomized-prims-algorithm-in-java-just-generate/61749486#61749486).